# The entire table is not displayed even when rotating package is used

Tags: tables

I have some tables with wider column content, I have 8 columns. The whole table is not displayed in LaTeX, when I reduce the font size also there is no result. I have about 7 tables in single `.tex` document. If I use the `rotating` package all the tables are not displayed.

Is there any other method to do this?

Sample code is

```
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrr}
 \hline
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ 
 \hline
 1 & 12415511.19 & 16701825.51 & 15900722.85 & 15877444.88 & 14925846.69 & 16530962.02 & 18141617.44 & 11153054.43 \\ 
  2 & 17903734.11 & 19022573.06 & 11578499.58 & 15541295.10 & 10988554.35 & 15442721.46 & 12145938.12 & 10013197.04 \\ 
  3 & 11485382.84 & 13734225.54 & 11732796.07 & 10783052.58 & 17693595.62 & 17765344.54 & 19073123.45 & 15398908.36 \\ 
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: What command from the `rotating` package are you using to rotate your tables? Are you interested in rotating a `table` or a `tabular`?

Comment: @Werner I am using tabular...i got the code from R and I was suggested to use tabular..I am a newbie in latex

Comment: @Werner I am also looking to add caption for each table, can you suggest..thank you

Comment: I have known the solution just we have to add small command for the table we want to reduce the width between center and tabular
 
    \begin{center}
    \small\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-6pt}
     \begin{tabular}
     

Thank you for all the help. It is appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

The tables could bee too big. You could try one of these options:

- reduce the font size (as you did)
- reduce the spacing (`\tabcolsep`, `@{}`)
- scale the table by `\scalebox` of the `graphicx` package
- shrink it by `\resizebox` of `graphicx`